# Exclude weekends days from the holidays

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

table leave has following data:-

```
EMPNO   NAME    DATEFROM                   DATETO
111     xxx   2014-08-03  00:00:00.000    2014-09-05  00:00:00.000
```

now i am fetching the data from leave table:

```
SELECT   [NAME],
         sum(datediff(day, DATEFROM, case 
                                         when dateto > '2014-08-31' then '2014-08-31'
                                         else dateto 
                                     end)+1) as holiday
FROM     [leave]
where    DATEFROM >= '2014-08-01'
         and DATEFROM <= '2014-08-31' 
         and userid = 1
group by name
```

it gives me below answer which is perfect:-

```
NAME   holiday 
xxx     29
```

but i want to to exclude the weekends(friday and saturday) from the holiday days...but it must exclude from the date 2014-08-03 (it is in leave table and datefrom column)

how can i perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following query in order to calculate holiday between two day:

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(WEEK,StartDate,EndDate)-1) * 2 +
        CASE DATEPART(dw,StartDate)
            WHEN 4 THEN 2
            WHEN 5 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
```

Comment: I edit my answer. you can use DATEPART in order to get day number of week.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use
`DATEPART(dw, DATEFROM) BETWEEN 1 and 5`  this will give you sunday to thursday.

sun = 1, mon = 2, tue = 3, wed = 4, thu = 5, fri = 6, sat = 7

however, i think the number relation to the day could be related to your system settings

Comment: it gives error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'

Comment: is this what you had?
`SELECT   [NAME],
         sum(datediff(day, DATEFROM, case 
                                         when dateto > '2014-08-31' then '2014-08-31'
                                         else dateto 
                                     end)+1) as holiday
FROM     [leave]
where    DATEFROM >= '2014-08-01'
         and DATEFROM <= '2014-08-31' 
         and userid = 1
         and DATEPART(dw, DATEFROM) BETWEEN 1 and 5
group by name`

Comment: we need more details about your table...    
  
i wrote the sql below and it works fine.    
  
`declare @leave table(
 EMPNO int
 , NAME varchar(max)
 , DATEFROM datetime
 , DATETO datetime
 , userid int
)

insert into @leave
select 111, 'xxx', '2014-08-03', '2014-09-05', 1

SELECT   [NAME]
,          sum(datediff(day, DATEFROM, case when dateto > '2014-08-31' then '2014-08-31' else dateto end)+1) as holiday 
FROM     @leave 
where    DATEFROM >= '2014-08-01'          
and DATEFROM <= '2014-08-31'           
and userid = 1          
and DATEPART(dw, DATEFROM) BETWEEN 1 and 5 
group by name`

Comment: sorry...i dont know how to add line breaks...im still new

Answer (score 0):

Try thethis `DATENAME()` function:

```
select [your_date_column]
from table
where DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [date_created]) <> 'Friday' 
  and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [date_created]) <> 'Saturday'
  and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [date_created]) <> 'Sunday'
```

Hope This may help you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding following where clause in your query should help:

```
DATEPART(dw,datefrom) not in(5,6)
```

This query will exclude all the Fridays and Saturdays from the result. Check DateFirst values [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181598.aspx) for more information.

Comment: it gives error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'not'

Comment: Can you update your question with the updated query you are using? I am assuming datefrom is a column in your table with datetime as data type.

Answer (score 0):

check it

```
SELECT   [NAME],
         sum(datediff(day, DATEFROM, case 
                                         when dateto > '2014-08-31' then '2014-08-31'
                                         else dateto 
                                     end)+1) as holiday
FROM     [leave]
where    DATEFROM >= '2014-08-01'
         and DATEFROM <= '2014-08-31' 
         and userid = 1 and datepart(dw,DATEFROM)<>6 and datepart(dw,DATEFROM)<>7
group by name
```